# How do I talk to engineers about vector components?

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, notation, geometry

I'd like to make what I regard as a very simple Pythagorean point using notation that engineers will be familiar with. I am not an engineer. Here we go:

Let there be some vectors (in 2-space) that meet two constraints. First, their magnitudes are each $c$. Second, the average magnitude of their $x$-axis components is $a$. The point I want to make is that from these two conditions it follows that the average magnitude of their $y$-axis components is $b$, where $b^2 = c^2 - a^2$.

Talking/corresponding with them they seem to hear me as starting with vectors of magnitude $c$ then *adding* vectors, but I'm just trying to make a very simple point about this Pythagorean relation holding of the vector components. How do I make this point about components of vectors with magnitude $c$ without making it seem like I'm adding vectors to vectors with magnitude $c$?

Comment: Engineers are usually perfectly well versed in vectors. I am not sure what you are asking? How to obfuscate what you are doing to people who can follow what you are doing in standard language just fine?

Comment: (some) engineers are intelligent life forms

Comment: Kind of related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: FlatterMan, I'm asking for help using notation correctly to distinguish between describing a vector's components and adding another vector to it. I'm certainly not suggesting they don't understand vectors. Thought it was clear I need help with notation, not them.

Comment: I expect that the problem is that your engineer friends are giving you the benefit of the doubt by assuming you are trying to express something true.  When you say something that appears obviously false, they go into contortions to re-interpret what you're saying.  If you want to prevent such contortions, the best way is to start by saying something that is actually true.

Answer (score 6):

First off, your claim is not true. Consider $v_1=(0, 1)$ and $v_2=(1, 0)$ so $|v_1|=|v_2|=c=1$. Their average $x$ component is $a=1/2$ and their average $y$ component is $b=1/2$ but

$c^2-a^2 = 1-(1/2)^2 = 3/4 \not= b^2=1/4$

Second, regarding speaking to engineers: For this specific topic I would recommend using algebraic equations and diagrams. Either hand-drawn sketches or to-scale diagrams made in software.

vectors are often denoted by letters like $u, v, w$ though many others are also used. Sometimes you can bold the letters or put an arrow over them to especially indicate they represent vectors: $\mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}$ or $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$.

Components of vectors can be indicated with subscripts. For example $\mathbf{v} = (v_x, v_y)$.

Magnitudes are indicated with vertical lines: $|\mathbf{v}|^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2$.

If you're concerned about confusing subscripts to enumerate vectors (i.e. $\mathbf{v}_1$ is a different vector than $\mathbf{v}_2$ compared to $v_x$ indicating the $x$ component of $\mathbf{v}$) you can use superscripts (in brackets to avoid confusion with exponentiation) to enumerate vectors and reserve subscripts for indicating components of vectors. e.g. $v^{(1)}_x$ is the $x$ component of the first vector $\mathbf{v}^{(1)}$ while $v^{(2)}_y$ is the $y$ component of the second vector $\mathbf{v}^{(2)}$. You could also use double indices like $v_{1, x}$ is the $x$ component of the first vector $\mathbf{v}_1$.

Comment: Python demo, with uniform & normal distributions: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkk1PwzAMhu-T9h-scViCCqMcOCAiceLIAXFDUxWt7hZpTUs-oBXiv2M37SgTOfjg93kd28kFvGhbNjVEawJ84C40DmrU1i8XlaO8S7Kp28YF8IhlNuYy2OvoiVsuSqyg7cNBdPJ-uQA6DkN0Fvy7CyKHK-guOzmRg81oKyaY78vAm32tQUG-uc0o3CXt82COCK8u4gjz6QgbqoiZVf7qpoIbeFDEUchnxllrHbfzaGxAp3chdVaI4Iw-epXf0EmDFjyzWq8zXlHVuFpxMxnoGJoitqUOqJ7Ig9M0zIuT8xrtrilRSG7qlAUkAzw3FseuWaGhpm1X02UJnDaW2BR5B2_MU2kioQBj2b_HcQi5TWDP4PA6MZGRyW77p1jBiyTQx5oeETaQaowV5mp_rqbYOlqlqFZfqZT6XskzIX2QQZX_yP3J9wM0PL-5&lang=python

Comment: Thank you, Jagerber48. I should have said they had positive x components.

Comment: @Anasker:  Consider a large set of vectors uniformly distributed on the unit circle in the first quadrant (i.e., all vectors have positive $x$-  and $y$-components.) The average $x$-component is $\frac{1}{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos \theta \, d\theta = 2/\pi$, as is the average $y$-component.  But $(2/\pi)^2 \neq 1 - (2/\pi)^2$.

Comment: @Anasker $v_1 = (0.9, 0.1)$ and $v_2 = (0.1, 0.9)$ so $c^2 = 0.82$. Average $x$ component is $a = 0.5$ and average $y$ component is $b=0.5$. $c^2 - a^2 = 0.57 \not = b^2 = 0.25$. Your claim is generically false and is probably only true for very special cases like $v_1=v_2$.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Yep, it's clearly false, even with the added qualifier about positive x components as you and others have shown. Thank you very much for the notation tips. This is quite new to me.